# Firebase cloud function uploading data to the cloud firebase deletes the data without any reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hello so a little bit of background.
I created a function in JS that fetches some data(multiple objects that can change in number every time I fetch the data ad example : fetch1: I get 3 obj  | fetch2: I get 1 obj,  I CAN NOT GET 0 obj ) from a website every minute, processes that data, and then sends it to the cloud firestore. The problem is that after the upload of the data, the doc and the collection get deleted without any reason at all and I don't understand what is happening.

I tried to search online but I could not find a fix.

Can anyone give me a hint of what is happening ?

This is the function in JS

```
import functions = require("firebase-functions");
import admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();
import https = require("https");
let finalData: { [x: string]: any; }[] = [];
const page = 1;
const fiat = "";
const tradeType = "";
const asset = "";
const payTypes = [""];
const baseObj = {
  page,
  rows: ,
  publisherType: ,
  asset,
  tradeType,
  fiat,
  payTypes,
};
const stringData = JSON.stringify(baseObj);
const options = {
  hostname: "",
  port: ,
  path: "",
  method: "",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Content-Length": stringData.length,
  },
};


const req = https.request(options, (res: any) => {
  finalData = [];
  let output = "";
  res.on("data", (d: string) => {
    output += d;
  });
  res.on("end", () => {
    try {
      const jsonOuput = JSON.parse(output);
      const allData = jsonOuput["data"];
      for (let i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {
        let payTypesz = "";
        for (let y = 0; y < allData[i]["adv"]["tradeMethods"].length; y++) {
          payTypesz += allData[i]["adv"]["tradeMethods"][y]["payType"];
          if (y < allData[i]["adv"]["tradeMethods"].length - 1) {
            payTypesz += ", ";
          }
        }
        const obj = {
          tradeType: allData[i]["adv"]["tradeType"],
          asset: allData[i]["adv"]["asset"],
          fiatUnit: allData[i]["adv"]["fiatUnit"],
          price: allData[i]["adv"]["price"],
          surplusAmount: allData[i]["adv"]["surplusAmount"],
          maxSingleTransAmount: allData[i]["adv"]["maxSingleTransAmount"],
          minSingleTransAmount: allData[i]["adv"]["minSingleTransAmount"],
          nickName: allData[i]["advertiser"]["nickName"],
          monthOrderCount: allData[i]["advertiser"]["monthOrderCount"],
          monthFinishRate: allData[i]["advertiser"]["monthFinishRate"],
          advConfirmTime: allData[i]["advertiser"]["advConfirmTime"],
          payTypes: payTypesz,
          position: 0,
        };
        finalData.push(obj);
      }
      console.log(finalData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
});
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("* * * * *")
    .onRun((context: any) => {
      req.write(stringData);
      req.end();
      for (let i = 0; i < finalData.length; i++) {
        database.doc("/$i")
            .set({
              "tradeType": finalData[i]["tradeType"],
              "asset": finalData[i]["asset"],
              "fiatUnit": finalData[i]["fiatUnit"],
              "price": finalData[i]["price"],
              "surplusAmount": finalData[i]["surplusAmount"],
              "maxSingleTransAmount": finalData[i]["maxSingleTransAmount"],
              "minSingleTransAmount": finalData[i]["minSingleTransAmount"],
              "nickName": finalData[i]["nickName"],
              "monthOrderCount": finalData[i]["monthOrderCount"],
              "monthFinishRate": finalData[i]["monthFinishRate"],
              "advConfirmTime": finalData[i]["advConfirmTime"],
              "payTypes": finalData[i]["payTypes"],
              "position": finalData[i]["position"],
            });
      }
      return console.log("Succes Upload of the data ");
    });
//  # sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

This is the setup of the DB.
[image]

Comment: Can you show your entire code. In particular, what exactly is `req`, `finalData` and `database`? In addition what exactly happens with "the doc and the collection get deleted". Do you have only one doc in this collection, with DocId = `0`?

Comment: req is the function that does the request and returns the object finalData.  database allows me to access the db.  When I say the doc and collection get deleted means that they disappear from the DB.  The collection contains 1 2 3 docs depending on the req function because the function can fetch 1 2 3 4 obs and each obj becomes a doc. Hope I said everything.  When I have 2 objs fetched the DB will have collection("Test).doc(1,2)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It seems that you are not managing at all the asynchronous character of the methods you call, i.e. `req`, `set`. Without you full code it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: I put all the code, hope that this will help because I really need to make this work 100%. thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

By default `https` for Node.js [does not return Promises](https://www.google.com/search?q=node.js%20https%20promise), therefore it can be cumbersome to [correctly manage the life cycle](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) of your Cloud Function.

I would suggest you use the [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library and refactor your code as follows, using a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to write to Firestore:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("* * * * *")
    .onRun(async (context: any) => {   // <=== See async keyword here
        
        try {
            const httpCallResponse = await axios.get(...); // I let you adapt the code, including the URL to call, according to the axios doc
            const finalData = ... // Again, it's up to you to work out the value based on httpCallResponse
            
            const batch = database.batch();
    
            for (let i = 0; i < finalData.length; i++) {
                batch.set(database.doc(i.toString(10)),
                    {
                        "tradeType": finalData[i]["tradeType"],
                        "asset": finalData[i]["asset"],
                        "fiatUnit": finalData[i]["fiatUnit"],
                        "price": finalData[i]["price"],
                        "surplusAmount": finalData[i]["surplusAmount"],
                        "maxSingleTransAmount": finalData[i]["maxSingleTransAmount"],
                        "minSingleTransAmount": finalData[i]["minSingleTransAmount"],
                        "nickName": finalData[i]["nickName"],
                        "monthOrderCount": finalData[i]["monthOrderCount"],
                        "monthFinishRate": finalData[i]["monthFinishRate"],
                        "advConfirmTime": finalData[i]["advConfirmTime"],
                        "payTypes": finalData[i]["payTypes"],
                        "position": finalData[i]["position"],
                    });
            }
            
            await batch.commit();
            console.log("Succes Upload of the data ");
            
            return null;
           
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Extra Note: Note that with your code you create monotonically increasing IDs and that [could be a problem](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#high_read_write_and_delete_rates_to_a_narrow_document_range).

Comment: Much appreciation and respect, I will try it tonight once I get home. Thank you again for your time and the help.

Comment: Hello @Alex97, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Hello, yes I actually had time to check it but after a couple of minutes I saw the problem reading again the documentation. So when using NodeJS basically firebase documentation suggest to use the following: db.collention().doc().set.  In my code I did : db.doc().set.() so that is why I got the error. Once I fixed as suggested by the documentation everything worked perfectly. Your suggestion worked 90% tho I had some problems with the options of the http, for the rest everything worked.